# Ubuntu - Trying to compile filezilla

Tags: ubuntu, filezilla, compile

I am trying to compile filezilla following the instructions on their site, but when i do the sudo ./configure command it tells me i'm missing libfilezilla:

> checking for LIBFILEZILLA... no
>   configure: error: libfilezilla not found. You can download it from https://lib.filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 3):

Download and install [LIBFILEZILLA](https://lib.filezilla-project.org/) and compile it. It is a dependency of Filezilla, but it isn't mentioned in the documentation for some reason.

In case you didn't know there is a filezilla package in the Ubuntu repositories

`sudo apt-get install filezilla`

you may also want to look at [this](https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/10678)

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. They should fix their documentation...

Comment: Infact not, it's still bothering about the LIBFILEZILLA...

Comment: @JojoCoana Your second comment, Does that mean Filezilla still isn't compiling?

Comment: if it's still not compiling I would do an apt-get install for Filezilla and then try compiling - The idea here is to install all the dependencies from apt-get automatically, so when you compile you *should* have all the needed dependencies installed.

Comment: I did just that, and it still complains about libfilezilla

Comment: It's possible that the version of libfilezilla in the repository does not match the version specified in the source (Ubuntu isn't the most up-to-date system when it comes to software packages). I would file a bug report on the filezilla website, try get the developers' attention on this issue.